# All buttons and dropdown menu not working after put in iframe

Tags: c#, iframe, model-view-controller, smartadmin

I'm using `C#` and SmartAdmin to build my web page.

Everything working fine until I put in `iframe` code.

This is my codes:

```
iframe id="displayFrame" src="@Url.Content("~/ReportViewer/UserListingReportViewer.aspx")" style="width:100%; height:1000px"
```

All `buttons` and `dropdown` menu is not working after i put in codes above.

Please advice.

Comment: read more about IFRAME... https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp  Iframe block script execution

Comment: I have tried all sandbox property but no one working. All buttons and dropdown menu still not working